# Silverlight 4: StackPanel doesn't resize, when content gets more narrow

Tags: silverlight, stackpanel

I am using Silverlight 4 with Blend 4.

I have a (horizontal) stackpanel that includes some TextBoxes and a Button. The stackpanel is set to stretch to the size that the content uses. The TextBoxes are on autosize too.

When I add text to the Textboxes, the textbox size grows and the stackpanel grows too. So far so good.

When I remove text from the textboxes, the textbox size shrinks (as excepted), but the stackpanel size doesn't.

Is there any trick to make the stackpanel change size, when the content (textboxes) getting smaller?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Here is the XAML for the UserControl:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
  <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelBorder" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxCharacteristicName" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Tex">
        </TextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxSep" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="=" IsReadOnly="True">
        </TextBox>
    <Button x:Name="ButtonRemove" Content="-" Click="ButtonAddOrRemove_Click">
        </Button>
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your StackPanel to resize horizontally with the items inside of it, you will need to change the HorizontalAlignment from the default value of "Stretch" to something else.

By default, the stackpanel stretches to fill the entire space of its parent control because the HorizontalAlignment is set to stretch.  This makes it difficult for it to grow and shrink in size.

You will want to set the HorizontalAlignment to "Left", "Right" or to "Center".  Then the stackpanel will only be as wide as the items inside of it.  But choose wisely, because the stackpanel will then dock to that position inside of its parent control.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
```

Note: If this isn't fixing your problem, then you have a problem with the Parent Control and not your StackPanel.

[MSDN website for HorizontalAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.horizontalalignment(VS.95).aspx)

Comment: Further tests showed (I put very nice background colors at each control), that the problem of not shrinking is with the listbox, that contains the UserControls. I wrapped the UserControls in ListBoxItems to be able to set the HorizontalAlignment for the items of the list (and they are now shrinking accordingly). I set the ListBox' HA on .Left too (as I did with almost every control). Still, no shrinking of the ListBox when the ListBoxItems shrink.

Comment: Gotcha.  It sounds like an opportunity for another question on StackOverflow.  I'd have to see code.  There are two things you could override, one of which is the ListBox's ItemsPanel and the other is the ItemContainerStyle.  Once again.. I'd have to see more code.

Comment: Hi Jeremiah. I have taken the opportunity and asked a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110159/silverlight-4-listbox-doesnt-shrink-when-its-items-shrink If you need more code, just let me know. Thanks anyway, Frank!

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using a `Grid` for this.  Just create a `Grid` with 3 auto columns and it will size to fit the content.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxCharacteristicName" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Tex" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxSep" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="=" IsReadOnly="True" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Button x:Name="ButtonRemove" Content="-" Click="ButtonAddOrRemove_Click" Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>
```

In most cases, you are much better off using a `Grid`.  The StackPanel is a useful control, but I often feel it is overused.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code as below.  Please check.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
  <ScrollViewer x:Name="PageScrollViewer" >
  <toolkit:WrapPanel x:Name="mywrapPanel" Orientation="Vertical" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LayoutRoot}">
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxCharacteristicName" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Tex" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=mywrapPanel}">
        </TextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxSep" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="=" IsReadOnly="True" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=mywrapPanel}">
        </TextBox>
    <Button x:Name="ButtonRemove" Content="-" Click="ButtonAddOrRemove_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="80" Margin="2">
        </Button>
  </toolkit:WrapPanel>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

If you use Horizontal in Orientation of WrapPanel, you may have to use the Height property binding with ActualHeight.  "toolkit" can be included in header as xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

you need something like:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
```

Also, I don't think that have a textbox which stretches is a good idea, unless it is a requirement.  You should specify the width on the textbox so it doesn't stretch.

Also, if the above solution doesn't work then you should post your xaml for letting us see the document outline.

Comment: HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" is standard for the StackPanel and I didn't changed it. It stretches fine, when the textboxes get bigger, but not, when they get smaller. Why shouldn't I allow the textboxes to stretch depending on the containing string? And I added the XAML of the UserControl. Really nothing fancy.

Comment: From the above code: how would you know that the stackpanel is not shrinking?